# must have an argument of class or enumerated type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class mSet
{
    private:

        mSet *next;
        int element;

    public:
        mSet();
        mSet(int n);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, mSet*);
    friend mSet* operator+ (mSet*, mSet*);
    friend mSet* operator/ (mSet*, mSet*);

    mSet* operator= ( mSet* b);

};
```

I would like to overload the + and the / operators, but i have this error:
'mSet* operator/(mSet*, mSet*)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type

Comment: Why pointers? You can't overload pointer arithmetics.

Comment: And why would you want to overload the operator for *pointers* to your objects?

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to add two pointers?

I think you should write

```
friend mSet& operator+ (const mSet&, const mSet&);
```

Comment: I work with linked lists. I would not like to use const.

Comment: @oridaniel Are you serious :)

Comment: @oridaniel those `const` keywords there don't mean that you won't be able to change them anymore. It just means that your `operator+` will not modify them (and why should it in the first place?). For example, if you have something like `int a = 2; int b = 3; int c = a + b;` do you expect that this sum will modify `a` or `b`? Clearly not. The + shouldn't touch `a` and `b`, it should *read* their values and use them to calculate the result. Adding `const` there is a guarantee, enforced by the compiler, that you won't accidentally mess with the operands. It won't limit you in any way.